# Error processing data for d3 bar chart

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js, charts

I am getting an error with a slightly modified version of Mike's bar chart template at http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304.

All I have done is substitute my own data (as a JS array for the purposes of JSFiddle) and the line immediately after the data loading, namely

```
x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.name; }));
```

fails with an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

There must be something obvious I'm missing but I can't see it. Please let me know! My fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8Hq3u/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substitute references to `data` to `data.revenue` because of the way your data is structured.

Complete [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8Hq3u/1/).

NOTE: you will need to deal with the long x labels, but [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321) should help you. You should also adjust your y scale a bit.

Updated [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8Hq3u/2/) with adjusted data, per OP's request.

Comment: Thanks, @FernOfTheAndes. I'd prefer to just restructure the JSON. What's the best way to do that?

Comment: No problem, I updated the fiddle with the adjusted data.

Comment: That's OK, I just took out the "revenue" wrapper and it worked. Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8Hq3u/3/